# IF Statement in order by clause of Doctrine 2 query Symfony 2

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

Im trying to do an blog that shows all the comments and user will be able to post comments on reply on previously posted comments no to order then in the sql query so they will show up in order i keep getting the error.

```
SELECT c.userid, c.comment, c.reply, u.username, c.createdat, c.image, c.username as
ComUser FROM Bundle:Comments c LEFT JOIN Bundle:Users u WITH c.userid = u.id
WHERE c.articleid = 1 ORDER BY (CASE WHEN (c.parentid = 0) THEN c.id ELSE c.parentid END) 
c.createdat ASC
```

Gives Error: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 515: Error: Expected end of string, got 'CASE'

even tried normal way

```
ORDER BY IF(c.parentid = 0, c.id, c.parentid), c.createdat ASC
```

Gives Error: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 515: Error: Expected end of string, got '('

When i use the normal ORDERY BY IF() in normal sql code (not doctrine) it works fine.

Comment: Assume typo? ELSE .parentid END -- should be c.parentid...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

looks like you just have a typo. Your overall syntax is correct.

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN (c.parentid = 0) THEN c.id ELSE .parentid END c.createdat ASC
```

should be

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN (c.parentid = 0) THEN c.id ELSE c.parentid END, c.createdat ASC
```

Comment: Thank you, Sorry just made a typo, still getting the same error though.

Comment: @BoereWors you're missing a comma after `END` too. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 3):

Awsome!!!
Thanks for your help guys i just got it!

My Solution:

```
SELECT c.userid, c.comment, c.reply, u.username, c.createdat, c.image, c.username as
ComUser, (CASE WHEN (c.parentid = 0) THEN c.id ELSE c.parentid END) as OrderByComm
FROM Bundle:Comments c LEFT JOIN Bundle:Users u WITH c.userid = u.id
WHERE c.articleid = 1 ORDER BY OrderByComm, c.createdat ASC
```

I did the order by calculation in the select part.